# How to make a Flutter button use themed colors

Tags: flutter, button, widget, themes

I've created a Widget that's basically an ElevatedButton, except its width can be made proportional to the screen size (settable with WidthFactor).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FractionalButton extends StatelessWidget {

  final double widthFactor;
  final Widget child;
  final Function onPressed;

  FractionalButton({
    required this.widthFactor,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FractionallySizedBox(
      widthFactor: widthFactor,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed(),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Trouble is, it shows up gray instead of using the basic themed color of green.

[image]

```
ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {},
     child: const Text("Country"),
),
FractionalButton(
    widthFactor: 1,
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text("Password"),
),
```

How can I get my Widget to use the current theme colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an issue with the ElevatedButton but with the `onPressed` function you are passing to the custom ElevatedButton.

Instead of

```dart
final Function onPressed;
```

use

```dart
final VoidCallback onPressed;
```

or

```dart
final Function() onPressed;
```

and use it like below:

```dart
onPressed: onPressed,
```

Your `FractionalButton` will look like below.

```dart
class FractionalButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final double widthFactor;
  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  FractionalButton({
    required this.widthFactor,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FractionallySizedBox(
      widthFactor: widthFactor,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
The reason it was happening was you were not passing on `onPressed` properly to the custom ElevatedButton and it was set to the disabled mode.

Comment: That was it! Fast and informative.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with te declaration of the function
try this :

```
final void  Function() onPressed;
```

the whole code :

```
  class FractionalButton extends StatelessWidget {

    final double widthFactor;
    final Widget child;
    final void  Function() onPressed;

    FractionalButton({
      required this.widthFactor,
      required this.onPressed,
      required this.child,
    });

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: widthFactor,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          child: child,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

so when you use this widgets :

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text("Country"),
          ),
          FractionalButton(
            widthFactor: 0.5,
            onPressed: () {  },
            child: const Text("Password"),
          ),
```

this will be the result:

[image]

as you can see it use the same theme as the original ElevatedButton.